# Xamarin Forms Taking a photo on Android and Cropping it

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

I am supporting Android 4.4 (API 19) using Xamarin Forms.

I have a simple requirement of allowing the user to capture a card photo and then automatically cropping it to take exactly the card, the user just needs to press the shoot button. The UI of the interface in action is below:

[image]

I am currently using the deprecated `Android.Hardware.Camera` interface and I am struggling to crop the card automatically and ignore the rest of the photo, for this, I am going through all sort of arithmetic to no avail!

My questions:

1. For such an easy requirement can I use Android's camera intent for displaying an overlay like this one and cropping? Am I going so far by using the camera hardware interface directly?
2. The card is centered horizontally and vertically within a semi-transparent area. I have the following variables that I am trying to put together to crop the card in the right place:
   ScalingFactor (usually 1, 2, 3 Or 4), SemiTransWidthDp (Usually 360Dp), SemiTransHeightDp (Usually 400Dp to 700Dp), CardWidthDp (Usually 80% of the SemiTransWidthDp), CardHeightDp (It is CardWidthDp / 1.6)

CardXInDp = (SemiTransWidthDp - CardWidthDp) / 2

CardYInDp = (SemiTransHeightDp - CardHeightDp) / 2

CameraPreviewWidthPixel, CameraPreviewHeightPixel, PictureWidthPixel, PictureHeightPixel.

I am using SkiaSharp to crop, so I need to calculate the following:

cropCardLeftPixel = ?

cropCardTopPixel = ?

cropCardWidthPixel = ?

cropCardHeightPixel = ?

Am I going far? Can someone help me establishing a relationship between the parameters above to be able to crop the card? Do I need to consider including CameraPreviewHeight and width in the calculations?

Comment: You could refer to: https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo

Comment: This would be a nice addition to the library I´m doing https://github.com/xleon/CustomCamera. Actually I need to implement it soon.

Comment: Created an issue here: https://github.com/xleon/CustomCamera/issues/1